# Adicionar um caractere dinamicamente com PHP ou JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Existe alguma função que faça PHP ou JavaScript que faça adicionar um caracterere (no caso um número) quando um campo tiver somente  8 dígitos. dentro de um `input`. pois tenho um formulário onde existe o campo RG, e o RG é composto por 9 dígitos mais existem alguns usuários que tem um digito a menos e gostaria de que quando o usuário digitar o campo RG com apenas 8 dígitos ele salve no banco com um digito a mais que seria o `0`

Lembrando que está funcionando tudo normal em meu site só gostaria mesmo de que quando o usuário digitar o RG com um digito a menos ele salve com esse `0`

Link do [site](http://oticasreiban.com.br/index.php?route=account/register)

Comment: Você já viu o str_pad? https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Pode esclarecer melhor seu problema? Qual caractere será esse? Por quê necessita que ele seja inserido? Qual a função dele?

Comment: vou adicionar a pergunta

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss reformulei a pergunta acho que agora está mais claro oque preciso

Comment: Desculpe-me a sinceridade, mas isso parece-me gambiarra. Você quer alterar o RG do usuário? Depois como fará para saber se originalmente o usuário digitou 8 caracteres ou se realmente é 0 naquela posição? Você não deveria ter que fazer esse tipo de alteração para que o seu sistema funcione.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss  os usuários com o digito a menos não estão conseguindo concluir as compras e acredito que adicionar um 0 ou  um x no caso resolva o problema pois pelo que vi geralmente quanto se tem um digito a menos no RG e adicionado um x ou um 0 por isso acho válido fazer assim se puder me ajudar nessa fico muito agradecido não fui em quem desenvolvi o site e essa foi a unica solução que consegui pensar para o momento pois não manjo nada de opencart e não posso fazer uma alteração muito complexa para não comprometer o sistema

Comment: O problema é que no banco você deve ter usado CHAR(9), basta colocar VARCHAR(9), dai ele aceitaria tanto 8 como 9 caracteres sem precisar de gambiarra. rs

Comment: De fato o X é utilizado, o 0 eu não sei dizer. Se você tiver uma fonte oficial que diga que possa utilizar o 0, ok, pode fazê-lo, mas ainda assim seria melhor você alterar seu sistema para que aceite apenas os 8 dígitos.

Comment: @WendelRodrigues cara se for isso eu te amo vou testar

Comment: @WendelRodrigues mas CHAR também aceitaria 8 caracteres, apenas na memória o banco de dados iria preencher até completar as 9 posições. A diferença é apenas na ocupação da memória, não?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você saberia me informar como faço o código que insira o numero adiconal ? ou alguma documentação acredito que via JS seja mais facil

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é verdade, boiei aqui. Desculpem.
Kirito a resposta que eu dei creio que resolva, basta pegar o RG do usuário, se tiver só 8 vc adiciona um 0 e armazena no banco.

Answer (score 3):

Tem a função [`str_pad`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php):

```
<?php
print str_pad('45', 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // Gera "0000000045"
print str_pad('23', 10, "0", STR_PAD_BOTH);  // Gera "0000230000"
print str_pad('76', 10, "0");  // Gera "6700000000"
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta eu preciso adicionar isso em um campo especifico no caso um <input> no formulário como ficaria isso

Comment: eu adicionei isso no meu php e funciona mais preciso fazer com que funcione quando o usuario digitar no input um rg menor que 9 digitos ai ele adiciona um 0 no final não precisa exibir para o usuario mais se exibir nao tem problema  a ideia e que quando ele se cadastrar apareca no painel já com o digito 0 inserido caso o usuario tenha cadastrado apenas com 8 digitos por exemplo

Comment: Pois é, mas ele mostra esse painel só depois que cadastra, certo? Se você adiciona o 0 no cadastro quando ele for pro painel já deveria mostrar com o 0.

Comment: não amigo é porque e assim o usuário se cadastra no site que foi feito com opencart esses dados vão para o banco e são exibidos no painel administrativo e la se o cara tiver cadastrado o RG com 8 digitos aparece só os 8 se cadastrou com 9 aparece os 9 o problema e que quando o usuário cadastra o RG com 8 digitos ele não consegue efetuar a compra pq da erro te que ser com 9 por isso quero que quando ele se cadastrar com um RG com menos de 9 digitos o sistema adiciona so um 0 no final para poder ficar com 9 digitos

Comment: pelo que vi o código que vc mandou funciona mais preciso vincular ele ao meu input que e aonde o usuario digita o RG <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="RG" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control"> que é esse cara ai quando ele cadastrar o sistema ja adiciona o 0 no final do RG se for menor que 9

Answer (score 3):

Como comentado, o melhor seria mesmo adaptar para seu sistema aceitasse o valor do RG original do usuário, com 8 caracteres. Mas de fato é possível adicionar um caractere `X` ao final indicando que o mesmo não existe - o caractere `0` eu não sei afirmar, se você encontrar uma fonte confiável que diga isso, ok.

Com JavaScript é bem tranquilo; basta você tratar algum evento do campo ou formulário, verificar o comprimento do dado informado e adicionar o caractere desejado. Veja o exemplo abaixo, onde tratei o evento `submit` do formulário.

> Eu utilizei `return false` para bloquear a propagação do evento pois ele não é necessário aqui. No seu caso, este trecho deve ser removido para que o evento seja propagado corretamente.

```js
function valida() {
  let rg = document.getElementById("rg");
  let span = document.getElementById("alert");

  if (rg.value.length < 9) {
    rg.value = rg.value + "X";
    span.innerHTML = "Seu RG foi modificado com a inserção de um X ao final por questões de compatibilidade";
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return valida();">
  <label for="rg">
    RG:
    <input type="text" id="rg" name="rg">
    <div id="alert"></div>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Nota: eu adicionei um aviso da alteração do valor ao usuário. É **muito** importante que faça isso caso essa alteração seja visível ao usuário. Nesse caso, como bloqueei a propagação do evento, a alteração ficará visível. Caso contrário, você poderá mostrar esse aviso apenas quando for exibir o valor do RG no sistema; algo como *se houver um X no RG, exibe esta mensagem ...*, para deixar claro ao usuário o porquê de existir um caractere que ele não digitou.

Comment: amigo obrigado pela resposta me tira uma dúvida como meu site e feito no opencart e o input name está <input name="custom_field[account][2]"> não sei como então o meu let rg = document.getElementById("rg"); deveria ficar let custom_field[account][2]= document.getElementById("rg"); porem se eu chama-lo asim da erro existe uma forma de exibir assim ? desculpe ão manjo quase nada de opencart se puder me ajudar agradeço

Comment: Você não consegue editar o campo?

Comment: não posso editar porque ele perde todas as referencias com banco de dados e tudo mais tem alguma forma de inserir esse elemento <input name="custom_field[account][2]"> dentro da função que você criou

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com o Opercart, mas geralmente existe a opção de você definir atributos personalizados ao campo. Teria que ler na documentação.

Comment: Usa essa função e ao invés de colocar no `onSubmit` coloca no [`onBlur`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) do campo do RG: `<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="RG" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control" onblur="return valida();">` Só altera o ID do campo de `rg`para `input-custom-field2`

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho uma ideia, tenta usar Javascript.
Cria um ficheiro javascript coloque o seguinte código:

```js
$('.input-name').focusout(function(){
  var valor = $(this).val();
  if(valor.length < 9) $(this).val('0' + valor);   
});
```

Depois disso copia o nome input-name e adiciona uma classe com o valor input-name onde desejas ver esse efeito.

Lembre-se que este código vai adicionar o número zero logo que o utilizador retirar o cursor do campo e se o valor que estiver no campo for menor que 9.